# Android IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a no

Tags: android, exception, listview

OK will try and keep this short(ish). I have googled this to death and made a load of changes to my Android app but nothing is solving this one. I am no noobie, 20+ years programming.

Here is my scenario:

Tab Host, 3 tabs
1st tab has a viewflipper, which displays a listview in three distinct lists.

I am updating an ArrayAdapter for each list from an ArrayList, and when I am updating the ArrayList I am calling notifyDataSetChanged.I am also hiding and showing the ListView as a previous suggested fix for this.

BUT...
Every now and again I get the dreaded Force Close with

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

I am updating the adapter on the UI thread, in one place. I have added logging all over the place. I am happy to share logs / code, my blood, to solve this one.

I am running out of ideas and my hair is falling out.

Any ideas / suggestions???

If you want to see my app search for PodPlayer in the market. I just want the bloody thing stable.

Thanks hopefully in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Better way is to update ArrayAdapter by using `adapter.add()` method.
```

If you use this method there is no need to explicitly call `notifydataSetChanged()` method. add() method will do take care of that

Comment: ok made that change, and the app still works, now lets see if it's stable.

Comment: didnt work,
here is the crash report
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. ... [in ListView(2131296280, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class net.msc.PODPlayer.tabLibrary$AlbumArrAdapter)]

    ...
 
what I can see is that is following tabHost onResume, tabPlayer onResume etc is not being called.
  
I am controlling the updating of the adapter, 

ANY HELP PLZ. pissing me off

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be the tab, happens to me even now and I have no apps with tab....

Comment: I think I may have solved it using another post, only time will tell. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290806/how-to-solve-this-issuethe-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did-n/5029059#5029059)