# java.lang.IllegalStateException in android?

Tags: android, listadapter

I am using three tabs.when i click the tab, an activity starts that displays multiple listview with header.For that i use listadapter
and my code seems adapter.addsection`("Header String",new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.row,cursor,from,to);` then i set list using 
list.setadapter(adapter).It all works fine when i click the tab.My problem occurs, after i scroll my listview which is in another activity and 
press emulator back button and clicking tab.Now when i am clicking tab,my application crashes and logcat shows the following error.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(-1, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.t.s.SeperatedListAdapter)]
```

Whats the solution for this? I used adapter.notifydatasetchanged() to solve this.Eventhough i couldn't.

Comment: check the following answers from the links [stackoverflow][1] [stackoverflow][2] [stackoverflow][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132021/android-listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478649/listview-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-list
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290806/how-to-solve-this-issuethe-content-of-the-adapter-has-changed-but-listview-did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is: 
**your data is changed, when back to previous activity, the listview will auto refresh, this time system found the data changed but no notifyDataChanged invoke, so throw the error.**

so if another activity change the data, you can try: in your previous activity in method: `onResume`, try use `notifyDataChanged` to notify.

Comment: I used notifydatasetchanged wherever i can..eventhough it crashes.

Comment: @mercy: Am also facing the same issue did u got fix for this